# Why does elastic raise this exception "elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(check_hostname requires server_hostname)"?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, ssl

I'm trying to query elasticsearch from a python script, and an exception is raised.

I followed the official guides such as [this one](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#ssl-and-authentication).
But when I'm trying to query elasticsearch, no success. here is the exception:

```
File "C:\...\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 250, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError:
 ConnectionError(check_hostname requires server_hostname) caused by: ValueError(check_hostname requires server_hostname)
```

Here is my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection
from ssl import create_default_context
import ssl



context = create_default_context(cafile="certificate.pem")
es = Elasticsearch("https://localhost", ssl_context=context, http_auth=('username','password'))

res = es.search(index="dr_*", body = {
'size' : 10,
'query': {
    'match_all' : {}
}
})
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Looks like something related to this: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2435

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I also met such issue.

By default, the value of check_hostname in context is True, so you have to specify the server_hostname. Here is a simple solution, just add the following line after you create context

```
context.check_hostname = False
```

It should work without any issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the port in your example. Please verify the tutorial you mentioned and following snippet:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['localhost', 'otherhost'],
    http_auth=('user', 'secret'),
    scheme="https",
    port=443,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing `context.check_hostname = False` you make the connection insecure.

Use this constructor instead:

```
Elasticsearch(
   hosts=['ip_address'],,
   http_auth=('elastic', 'pass'),
   use_ssl=True,
   verify_certs=True,
   port=9200, #make sure of the port elasticsearch is using
   ca_certs='/Users/raphaeldelio/ca.crt'
)
```